# Can a function parameter be a function when called

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, ecmascript-6, parameters

I have a 2 functions:

```
const fn1 = (1, 2) => {
   //do something
}
```

```
const fn2 = ({param1, param2, param3}) => {
   $(`#id_one`).text(param1);
   $(`#id_two`).text(param2);
   param3;
}
```

Calling functions:

```
fn2({
   param1: 'hello',
   param2: 'world',
   param3: fn1(1, 2)
});
```

When I call the function above, **fn1() is getting called before fn2()**. Why is that happening? I need to go through fn2() before fn1().

Comment: It happens because `fn1()` has to be resolved in order to assign the property to `param3` which is needed in order to create the object, which is passed to `fn2`. It's all nested. It would perhaps be clearer if you explain why is it a problem that `fn1` doesn't need to be called and what you're trying to do in general.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`()` after an identifier that points to a function invokes the function. Since you want to invoke the function after everything in `f2` is done, put the `()`s inside `fn2`, not in the caller:

```
const fn2 = ({param1, param2, param3}) => {
   $(`#id_one`).text(param1);
   $(`#id_two`).text(param2);
   param3();
}
```

```
fn2({
   param1: 'hello',
   param2: 'world',
   param3: fn1
});
```

Comment: what if fn1() has paramters too? Sorry should've mentioned that in my question

Comment: Then you need to put those in the `()`: `param3(1, 2)`

Comment: @nb_nb_nb If it accepts, say, `1` and `2`, then I'd pass: `() => fn1(1, 2)` (if they're defined in the caller, but not in the `fn2` section)

Comment: @Barmar, inside param3()?

Comment: If you need to provide the parameters when calling `fn2()`, use an anonymous function: `param3: function() { fn1(1, 2); }`

Comment: @CertainPerformance, fn1(1,2) or param3(1,2);

Comment: @nb_nb_nb It depends where the parameters need to be defined. If inside `fn2`, then use the code in the answer but pass the parameters to `param3`. If outside `fn2`, then `() => fn1(1,2)` as the parameter passed to `fn2`.

Comment: @CertainPerformance, just confirm is I am understanding, if outside fn2, then I do fn2({
   param1: 'hello',
   param2: 'world',
   param3: () => fn1(1,2)
});

Comment: @nb_nb_nb Yes, like that

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the callback function into fn2 like this:

```js
fn2({
   param1: 'hello',
   param2: 'world',
   param3: fn1
});
```

and call fn1 from fn2 like this:

```js
const fn2 = ({param1, param2, param3}) => {
   $(`#id_one`).text(param1);
   $(`#id_two`).text(param2);
   param3();
}
```

Whenever you use the parentheses, the function is immediately invoked.

What you're currently dong `param3: fn1()` is saying "param3 is equal to the return value of this function" and it runs fn1() to get the return value, even if the function doesn't return anything.